Installing mutually-exclusive packages (Postfix, Exim) on Ubuntu
I am trying to install, and use simultaneously, both Postfix and Exim on a single Ubuntu 24.04 system with two IP addresses.  I've done the work of configuring each MTA to use its own discrete IP address, so that they don't conflict.  However, I can't install one package without uninstalling the other:
# apt install postfix
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  postfix-cdb postfix-doc postfix-ldap postfix-lmdb postfix-mta-sts-resolver postfix-mysql postfix-pcre postfix-pgsql postfix-sqlite procmail
  ufw
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  exim4 exim4-base exim4-config exim4-daemon-light
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postfix
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

How can I resolve the conflict so that both can be installed at the same time? (And not just install them, but live free of the fear that routine upgrades will knock one of them out).
I am aware that as an alternative I could compile one from source and install it; that would lack the automatic updates that using distro packages provide and would lack the OS-specific tweaks (systemd, I'm looking at you) so I would prefer not to do that.

How about running one of them with docker?

After 12 hours of work with docker I had a mail server that declined to accept mail, refused to send mail, and couldn't accept mail injected locally by a cgi-bin.  After 3 hours more, I had a local copy installed from source that works in all particulars, including systemd integration, co-existing with Postfix, and handling cgi-bin email.  Maybe somebody with sharper docker skills could finesse it, but apparently not me.

This is impossible to do with distro packages, it's exactly where the mutual exclusion is specified. The only safe way to go around it in Debian and derivatives is to create you own packages or recreate (repack) existing DEBs, omitting the conflicting mutual exclusions. (You may to to this to one of the two packages, in which case you have to change its name or remove the Provides field, so it won't trigger the mutual exclusion from the other package.)
That would lack the automatic updates from upstream repositories, of course, because it would mean you aren't using packages from these anymore.
Serously, accept the suggestion in the comment. Use containers.
